# How to represent "money down on new contract" in general journal (general ledger)

Tags: small-business, accounting

How would the following scenario be represented as a general journal entry?

- Jan 1, 2011:  Customer signs contract for $1000 and pays $500 as a down payment and agrees to pay the remaining $500 at a later date

I am VERY new to accounting but my guess is that we are dealing with 3 accounts:  Cash, Accounts Receivable and Revenue.  If this is correct, how would the journal entry look?

Comment: Better question for [onstartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/)

Comment: It's more of a bookkeeping question than a startup question, so I think it's more appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, let's see, I always get Credit and Debit mixed up, but I'll try:

**Signing of the contract:**

- Debit Accounts Receivable $1000
- Credit Revenue $1000

**Receiving 500 deposit:**

- Credit Accounts Receivable $500
- Debit Cash $500

When you are done Accounts Receivable will have $500 (because you are owed $500), Revenue will have $1000 (because you made $1000 on an accrual basis), and Cash will have $500 (because you have $500 in your pocket).